# Convert raw SQL query to Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need your help, guys. I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users
where lcase(concat(firstname, ' ', lastname)) like lcase(concat('%', replace('%searchterm%', ' ', '%'), '%'))
OR lcase(concat(lastname, ' ', firstname)) like lcase(concat('%', replace('%searchterm%', ' ', '%'), '%'))
OR lcase(location) like lcase('%searchterm%')
```

Is it possible to use a nice eloquent query instead of DB::select(DB::raw()) to use pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `whereRaw` and `orWhereRaw` methods on a Eloquent Builder to use raw expressions while maintaining the ability to get model instances as a result.

The advantages is that you can still use PDO parameter binding and therefore avoid SQL Injections though `$searchTerm`.

You can also find out more about raw expressions in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-expressions);

```php
// Assuming $searchTerm contains the term that you need to search the database for

$users = User::whereRaw('lcase(concat(firstname, " ", lastname)) like lcase(concat("%", replace("%?%", " ", "%"), "%"))', [ $searchTerm ])
    ->orWhereRaw('lcase(concat(lastname, " ", firstname)) like lcase(concat("%", replace("%?%", " ", "%"), "%"))', [ $searchTerm ])
    ->orWhereRaw('lcase(location) like lcase("%?%")', [ $searchTerm ])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

To split your `where` condition you can use [orWhere](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) method.

```php
User::
  ->where(DB::raw('condition_one'))
  ->orWhere(DB::raw('condition_two'))
  ->orWhere(DB::raw('condition_three'))
  ->paginate();
```

Comment: You should use `User::where` or `User::query()->where` otherwise you will get a syntax error. I would advise against using raw expressions with user provided input (as it may lead to sql injections)